# Newbie looking for an interesting introductory book to telecommunication and signals/data processing

Tags: digital-communications, reference-request

I am currently in my first year of Bsc Applied Physics. Over the past two years, I have realized I'm interested in majoring in telecommunication after I finish my bachelor. Also, for one of my classes I need to give a presentation; I chose my topic to be about Data Transmission. While working on my abstract for my project, I came across things I never even thought of! This, however, sparked my interest in this field even more!

So is there any interesting introductory book to signals and telecommunication that you would suggest and that is interesting and accessible for a bachelor student?

Thank you very much!

Yours, 
WBk

Answer (score 4):

"Telecommunications" is too broad a subject: you could spend your entire life learning about just a small part of the field. However, you mention data transmission specifically; I'll recommend these books:

"Digital Signal Transmission" by C. C. Bissell and D. A. Chapman, Cambridge. This is an undergraduate level book that has very lucid coverage of both the physical layer and larger telecom networks.

"Principles of Digital Communicatios", by B. Rimoldi, Cambridge. This is an advanced undergrad textbook that focuses on the math and theory behind digital communications. A great book if you like that kind of thing.

"Data and Computer Communications", by W. Stallings, Pearson. I'm not the biggest fan of Stallings, but his books are very accessible and cover all the bases. In fact, it might be a good idea to start with this book and then continue with more rigorous books like the first two I listed.